# Angular 2: Cannot find name 'encodeUri'

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to use `http.get` to call a remote URL. I append a search string to the base URL. This search string should be URL encoded. But I get this error:

> Cannot find name 'encodeUri'

How should I import it or make it available? This is a standard Javascript function and I had the same problem trying to use the Javascript's `Math` object.

```
  search(term:string):any {
    let encoded_term:string = encodeUri(term);
    let url:string = [Config.API_BASE_URL, 'members', 'search', '?q=' + encoded_term].join('/');

    return this.http.get(url)
      .map(res => res.json())
      .map(res => {
        return this.buildPage(res);
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Function is called `encodeURI()`, not `encodeUri()`.

You can read more about `encodeURI()` and other Typescript predefined functions [here](https://narayanatechnicalworld.blogspot.rs/2016/05/predefined-functions-in-typescript.html).

Comment: Well, that was embarrassing. Thank you.